# Invoking methods containing Hibernate transaction on external JAR/CLASS using reflection (Java EE)

Tags: java, hibernate, reflection, glassfish-4

Good day! I'm having problem making hibernate work on a external jar which is loaded thru reflection on my EJB.
As of now I've tried three options but none of these works and just gives me error.

Here are a snippet of codes I've tried.
I also added comment to which line the error occurs in each option.

**OPTION 1. PASSING SESSION FROM EJB TO EXTERNAL JAR THRU HashMap/Map**

My Session Bean Class

```
public Object processRequest(Map parameters) {
    String runnerClass = (String) parameters.get("runnerClass");
    String value = (String) parameters.get("value");
    String jarPath = "csys.runner.jar";
    Object returnObj = null;
    try {
        parameters.put("sessionEjb", getSession());
        File f = new File(jarPath);
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURL()},
                System.class.getClassLoader());
        Class c = urlClassLoader.loadClass(runnerClass);
        Method m = c.getMethod("performService", new Class[]{String.class, Map.class});
        returnObj = m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[]{value, parameters});
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSysSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

External JAR Method

```
public Object performService(String value, Map<Object, Object> parameters) {
    this.session = (Session) parameters.get("sessionEjb");  // ERROR IN THIS PART ClassCastException
    return null;
```

it gives me this error.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl cannot be cast to org.hibernate.Session
```

**OPTION 2. PASSING SESSION FROM EJB TO EXTERNAL JAR VIA METHOD's PARAMETERS**
My Session Bean Class

```
public Object processRequest(Map parameters) {
    String runnerClass = (String) parameters.get("runnerClass");
    String value = (String) parameters.get("value");
    String jarPath = "csys.runner.jar";
    Object returnObj = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(jarPath);
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURL()},
                System.class.getClassLoader());
        Class c = urlClassLoader.loadClass(runnerClass);
        Method m = c.getMethod("performService", new Class[]{String.class, Map.class, org.hibernate.Session.class}); //ERROR IN THIS PART NoSuchMethodException
        returnObj = m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[]{value, parameters, getSession()});
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSysSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

External JAR Method

```
public Object performService(String value, Map<Object, Object> parameters, org.hibernate.Session session) {
    this.session = session;  
    return null;
}
```

now it throws me this error.

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: csys.server.main.runner.ProjectRunner.performService(java.lang.String, java.util.Map, org.hibernate.Session)
```

**OPTION 3. CREATING SESSION IN EXTERNAL JAR**

My Session Bean Class

```
public Object processRequest(Map parameters) {
    String runnerClass = (String) parameters.get("runnerClass");
    String value = (String) parameters.get("value");
    String jarPath = "csys.runner.jar";
    String configPath = "D:/config/hibernate.cfg.xml";
    Object returnObj = null;
    try {
        File f = new File(jarPath);
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(new URL[]{f.toURL()},
                System.class.getClassLoader());
        Class c = urlClassLoader.loadClass(runnerClass);
        Method m = c.getMethod("performService", new Class[]{String.class, Map.class, String.class}); 
        returnObj = m.invoke(c.newInstance(), new Object[]{value, parameters, configPath});
    } catch (MalformedURLException | ClassNotFoundException | NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(CSysSessionBean.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        throw new RuntimeException(ex);
    }
    return returnObj;
}
```

External JAR Method

```
public Object performService(String value, Map<Object, Object> parameters, String configPath) {
    Configuration configuration = new Configuration();
    configuration.configure(new File(configpath)); //ERROR IN THIS PART, COULD NOT PARSE CONFIGURATION
    SessionFactory sessionFactory = configuration.buildSessionFactory();
    this.session = sessionFactory.openSession();  
    return null;
}
```

now it throws me another error.

```
org.hibernate.HibernateException: Could not parse configuration: D:\config\hibernate.cfg.xml
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.doConfigure(Configuration.java:2163)
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.configure(Configuration.java:2133)
Caused by: org.dom4j.DocumentException: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory Nested exception: org.dom4j.DocumentFactory cannot be cast to org.dom4j.DocumentFactory
```

Note that executing hibernate transactions in my EJB project is working well, it's just executing from external jar gives me error.

Answer (score 0):

found the fix already.
the problem was with my ClassLoader.

```
System.class.getClassLoader()
```

should be

```
this.getClass().getClassLoader()
```